# discord.js - TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

If I press the button, the following error occurs: `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.` However, I can also put a solid id there and this error still occurs.

```
button.guild.channels.create('cs', {
            type: "text",
            parent_id: '802172599836213258',
            permissionOverwrites: [
               {
                 id: button.guild.roles.everyone,
                 deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
               },
               {
                id: button.clicker.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
              }
            ]
          })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DiscordJS 13 (maybe previous version as well), you must passed the type parameter for it to work if the role/user is not yet cached.

```
button.guild.channels.create('cs', {
            type: "text",
            parent_id: '802172599836213258',
            permissionOverwrites: [
               {
                 id: button.guild.roles.everyone,
                 deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
               },
               {
                id: button.clicker.id,
                type: "member",
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
              }
            ]
          })
```

### Explanation:

The reason why it does not work without the `type` is due to this code when creating a channel:
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/34ba9d1c4c80eff7e6ac199a40232d07491432cc/packages/discord.js/src/structures/PermissionOverwrites.js#L183

```
if (typeof overwrite.id === 'string' && overwrite.type in OverwriteType) {
  return {
    id: overwrite.id,
    type: overwrite.type,
    allow: PermissionsBitField.resolve(overwrite.allow ?? PermissionsBitField.DefaultBit).toString(),
    deny: PermissionsBitField.resolve(overwrite.deny ?? PermissionsBitField.DefaultBit).toString(),
  };
}
 

const userOrRole = guild.roles.resolve(overwrite.id) ?? guild.client.users.resolve(overwrite.id);
if (!userOrRole) throw new TypeError(ErrorCodes.InvalidType, 'parameter', 'User nor a Role');
const type = userOrRole instanceof Role ? OverwriteType.Role : OverwriteType.Member;
```

And here when using the `PermissionOverwriteManager`:

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/5d8bd030d60ef364de3ef5f9963da8bda5c4efd4/packages/discord.js/src/managers/PermissionOverwriteManager.js#L95

```
async upsert(userOrRole, options, overwriteOptions = {}, existing) {
    let userOrRoleId = this.channel.guild.roles.resolveId(userOrRole) ?? this.client.users.resolveId(userOrRole);
    let { type, reason } = overwriteOptions;
    if (typeof type !== 'number') {
      userOrRole = this.channel.guild.roles.resolve(userOrRole) ?? this.client.users.resolve(userOrRole);
      if (!userOrRole) throw new TypeError(ErrorCodes.InvalidType, 'parameter', 'User nor a Role');
      type = userOrRole instanceof Role ? OverwriteType.Role : OverwriteType.Member;
    }
    ....
```

If `type` is not given, then it will try to call `this.client.role.resolve` and `this.client.users.resolve` which will only check the cache.

Either update your cache by fetching the user/role, or precise the type to avoid to have to check the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible problem I can see is the `button.guild.roles.everyone`, there's no everyone property in `button.guild.roles`, the everyone id is the guild id, so if you replace `button.guild.roles.everyone` with `button.guild.id`, it should fix the problem.

```js
button.guild.channels.create('cs', {
  type: "text",
  parent_id: '802172599836213258',
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: button.guild.id,
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
    },
    {
      id: button.clicker.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Still not working. The problem is with ID, with the role it works great...

Comment: Try using button.user.id